# WPF mark and select controls

Tags: wpf, selection

I would like to know if any way to "mark" a group of controls in WPF and then retrive those controls in a `window.xaml.cs` function.

Due the layout of the window the controls cannot be grouped under any xaml 
structure.

I would like something like this

```
<Button Selection="selection" />
<Textbox />
<Label Selection="selection" />
```

-

```
function someEvent()
{
  //In here get a collection with the button and the Label using 'selection'
}
```

The important thing is that the identifier cannot be unique, I can't use `Name` and also must not be generic, I cant use `Label` or `Button`.

And finally as I said at the beggining, controls cannot be encolsed in any kind of group either. They may be encolsed separately.

Thank you all!

Comment: Option one: you can use the Tag property. Option two: create an attached property to represent the group.

Comment: As @Andrew says in his answer, if you're "retrieving a group of controls", there's probably a cleaner and much simpler way to do it, more in line with orthodox XAML practice. But if not, an attached property is absolutely the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment, WPF controls have a `Tag` property that can be used to add arbitrary information to a control. That said, a better solution is to implement an Attached Property that has both the correct type, and encapsulates the intent of your 'mark'.

From an 'XY problem' perspective, there is likely a more basic requirement that has led you to this specific question. Since you didn't include further details, all I can add is that there is likely a better way to handle things like enabling/disabling a set of controls, or even using an ItemsControl with a DataTemplate to treat the 'group' as a single entity. I recommend including scenario details in your SO questions.